# Unions between pointers and data, possible pitfalls?

Tags: c++, algorithm, types

I'm programming a system which has a massive amount of redundant data that needs to be kept in memory, and accessible with as little latency as possible.  (uncompressed, the data is guaranteed to absorb 1GB of memory, minimum).

One such method I thought of is creating a container class like the following:

```
class Chunk{
    public:
        Chunk(){ ... };
        ~Chunk() { /*carefully delete elements according to mask*/ };
        getElement(int index);
        setElement(int index);

    private:
        unsigned char mask;  // on bit == data is not-redundant, array is 8x8, 64 elements
        union{
            Uint32 redundant;  // all 8 elements are this value if mask bit == 0 
            Uint32 * ptr;      // pointer to 8 allocated elements if mask bit == 1
        }array[8];
};
```

My question, is that is there any unseen consequences of using a union to shift between a `Uint32` primative, and a `Uint32*` pointer?

Comment: I'd be a little concerned about assuming that a pointer is going to take the same space as a Uint32 -- not a major issue I suppose.

Comment: It would be safer to use `uintptr_t redundant;`

Comment: @Matthew - whoa... that is a thing that actually exists?  Holy moly, thank you!

Comment: @Clairvoire It's not required that a conforming implementation provide `uintptr_t`, though almost all will these days. If you really need just 32 bits, I would go with what you have – the space is wasted either way.

Comment: @the guy - I can modify the actual contents of the class to maximize for the common case.  a 64bit pointer, and two 32bit values, the second being used if only 1 of the 8 elements is different, for example

Comment: @Clairvoire Then it would probably be more convenient for you to do `union { Uint32 redundant[2]; Uint32* ptr; } array[8];`. I like `uintptr_t` a lot, but I really only use it when I'm playing with the low-order bits of a pointer or want to union a pointer with a value that shrinks and grows with the pointer type.

Comment: @theguyformerlyknownasd, like `intptr_t`, it's required to conform to XSI

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen What's XSI and why is it relevant here? Anyway, the availability of `uintptr_t` is more a theoretical issue than a practical issue, and my main point was that I can't think of a good reason why Clairevoire would want to control space usage and then just give up on the size of the int member.

Comment: @theguyformerlyknownasd, "The X/Open System Interface is the core application programming interface for C and sh programming for systems conforming to the Single UNIX Specification." See the [Open Group docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap02.html#tag_02_01_04) about XSI conformance.  I just mentioned it because you brought up conformance.  As I said, it's safer, but that's only really an issue if the code is doing something like `array[0].redundant = array[1].ptr;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach should be safe on all C++ implementations.

Note, however, that if you know your platform's memory alignment requirements, you may be able to do better than this. In particular, if you know that memory allocations are aligned to 2 bytes or greater (many platforms use 8 or 16 bytes), you can use the lower bit of the pointer as a flag:

```
class Chunk {
 //...
  uintptr_t ptr;
};

// In your get function:    
if ( (ptr & 1) == 0 ) {
  return ((uint32_t *)ptr)[index];
} else {
  return *((uint32_t *)(ptr & ~(uintptr_t)0);
}
```

You can further reduce space usage by using a custom allocation method (with placement new) and placing the pointer immediately after the class, in a single memory allocation (ie, you'll allocate room for `Chunk` and either the mask or the array, and have `ptr` point immediately after `Chunk`). Or, if you know most of your data will have the low bit off, you can use the `ptr` field directly as the fill-in value:

```
} else {
  return ptr & ~(uintptr_t)0;
}
```

If it's the high bit that's usually unused, a bit of bit shifting will work:

```
} else {
  return ptr >> 1;
}
```

Note that this approach of [tagging pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer) is unportable. It is only safe if you can ensure your memory allocations will be properly aligned. On most desktop OSes, this will not be a problem - malloc already ensures some degree of alignment; on Unixes, you can be absolutely sure by using `posix_memalign`. If you can obtain such a guarentee for your platform, though, this approach can be quite effective.

Comment: Amazing!  I think I'll reserve the pointer tagging for the end, in case it needs even further optimization.  But using placement new and appending the pointer is working great.  My test case is also 3-fold faster somehow.  I guess cache locality or something.

Comment: Yep, putting the chunks next to the actual data being pointed to could reduce cache footprint by up to half :) It also saves malloc overhead.

Answer (score 2):

If space is at a premium you may be wasting memory. It will allocate enough space for the largest element, which in this case could be up to be 64 bits for the pointer.

If you stick to 32-bit architectures you should not have problems with the cast.